# Net use: File copy works with drive letter, fails with UNC path

Tags: batch-file, net-use

I am trying to copy a file to a network location with a batch file:

```
net use F: \\my\destination\folder /user:myuser password
copy C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\toCopy.txt F:
```

Works like a charm. However, when I leave out the drive letter, I get an "Access Denied" error.

```
net use \\my\destination\folder /user:myuser password
copy C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\toCopy.txt \\my\destination\folder
```

I don't want to use a hardcoded drive letter - what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

`copy` command does not support UNC paths (by default but [it can be changed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156276)). You have two options: use `robocopy` or change current directory to remote path using `pushd` (which creates a temporary drive letter for you, removed by `popd`), see also [...UNC path...without mapping it to a network drive?](https://superuser.com/a/399885). Assuming you want to avoid virtual drives (otherwise your own solution works pretty well too):

```
robocopy "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop" "\\my\destination\folder" "tocopy.txt"
```

Note that `robocopy` has this syntax:

```
robocopy source destination [file [file]...] [options]
```

Then you first need to specify source and destination directories and then files to copy (wildcards allowed).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Two things: Robocopy also tells me Access Denied, and I just spoke with the client who uses it and she told me that it used to work without drive letter, with the normal "copy" command. I am puzzled.

Comment: @Tim it _may_ work also with copy (see link at very beginning of my answer). Be sure to specify a valid network path and...credentials. If it works with drive letter then it'll also work with UNC and robocopy (or _modified_ copy).

Comment: Pushd also gives me an access denied. I guess I'll have to stick to drive letters

Comment: I still don't understand why it works when a drive letter is attributed. The credentials are the same